# featured image as background image on pages

Tags: pages, post-thumbnails, custom-background

I'm adding a featured image on my page through the dashboard and I want to use it as a background image on the container div of the page.
I want to apply the background image through css, so I am thinking to put a style attribute inside my markup.
I'm thinking to make something like this:

```
<div id="<?php echo $post_name; ?>" class="page<?php echo $post_id; ?>" style="background: url(<?php wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large' ); ?>) !important;">
```

But unfortunately this is not working.

When I check the output is like this:

```
background: url() !important;
```

What is wrong with this ? 
Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: Have you [already searched the site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=background+image)?

Comment: Yes I did a research but it seems to not work proper, I've updated my question, check now please!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to `echo` the return value from `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`. It also returns an `Array()`, so you need to grab the needed part from that array. In this case it's the first/`0` value. Example:

```
<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>
<div id="post" class="your-class" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>')">
<p>your text demo</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain ***why*** this should help the OP. Thanks.

Comment: @kaiser was also working with backgrounds that way, I am newbie, do not know why, but I know it worked for what I saw in a forum.

Comment: @Feera Well, then it's _Magic_. And know that _Magic_ always is the answer :D

Comment: may be little, but what matters is the intention :P

Comment: If you're doing this in a function, don't forget to precede this code with `global $post;` .

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [the `the_post_thumbnail_url` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail_url):

> Gets the direct image URL for the featured image of the current post.

```
<div id="<?php echo post_name; ?>" class="page<?php 
echo $post_id; ?>" style="background: url(<?php 
echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post_id, 'large' ); ?>) !important;">
```